# Calculated field in SharePoint 2010 not returning correct average

Tags: infopath

I have designed a survery/questionaire in InfoPath and have it publishing to SharePoint 2010.  I used option buttons (whole number integer) to allow the users to select a rating for each question (values 1-4).  I am trying to get the average rating (per survey) to calculate in the SharePoint list but it is not returning the correct average.

Here is the formula I'm using:

```
 =AVERAGE([Q 1 Ratings],[Q 2 Ratings],[Q 3 Ratings],[Q 4 Ratings],[Q 5 Ratings],[Q 6 Ratings],[Q 7 Ratings],[Q 8 Ratings],[Q 9 Ratings],[Q 10 Ratings],[Q 11 Ratings],[Q 12 Ratings])
```

Any ideas of what I may have done wrong?

Comment: Can you include some example data and example output?

Comment: Sure, on one entry the value for Q1 Rating is 1 and the rest are 4s (one field = 1, eleven fields = 4) but the calculated average returned is 4 instead of 3.75.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but in your calculated field properties is it set up to only show one digit?

Comment: No, I have it set to show up to two decimals :)  On other entries it is showing more than one digit but its still wrong.  Example entry:  three = 1, six = 2, six = 3, three = 4 with a returned average of 3.33 instead of 2.5

Comment: I've never seen that problem before. Does the order affect the calculated value? If you use =SUM(...)/12 does the error remain?

Comment: That actually returns 1.33 :-(

Comment: If I was troubleshooting, I would start with a calculated column of `=[Q 1 Ratings]` and see if it is correct. Then set the column to `=SUM([Q 1 Ratings],[Q 2 Ratings])` and so on until something doesn't work correctly. You might have columns that are set as strings instead of numbers, or a misspelling, or maybe something else. That'll at least narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Validate all your 12 fields are actually numbers with

```
=ISNUMBER([Q 1 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 2 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 3 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 4 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 5 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 6 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 7 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 8 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 9 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 10 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 11 Ratings]) 
& ISNUMBER([Q 12 Ratings])
```

It should return TRUETRUETRUE....TRUE

if there is a FALSE in the string you've got a Text field instead of Number

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use a SP view.

Modify the view. Under the Totals section, select Average for the desired column.